# Vaadin Mobile application database connection

Tags: java, gwt-rpc, vaadin-touchkit

I am working on vaadin mobile application.  Where I need to connect to database. 
I have gone through many resources on web.  
All of them  mentioned two classes `component.client.SQLRunnerAsync` and `component.client.SQLRunner` class. 
But I am not able to find any jar containg these two classes, **can anyone please help me on this?**